# Why does select() always time out? (windows)

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock, select-function

I'm using select to try and wait for an acknowledgement from another host on the network, but it always returns 0. I've seen other threads with similar questions, and their problem is always either they aren't resetting the fd_set, or they're not passing in the right value for the first parameter of select(). That can't be what's causing my problem, because I am resetting the fd_set, and the first parameter is ignored in windows, apparently, according to msdn.

```
while(!done)
{
    //send acknowledgment and sequence number
    sendto(_clientSocket, buff, 2, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&_sockAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

    //wait for acknowledgment
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = _rttInfo.timeout/1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = _rttInfo.timeout * 1000;

    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(_clientSocket, &fds);

    //wait for client to send an acknowledgement
    //wait for the socket to be ready for reading
    int res = select(0, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    int err = WSAGetLastError();

    if(res == 0) //if timed out, retry
    {
        timedOutCount++;
        if(timedOutCount >= MAX_TIMEOUTS)
        {
            cout << "Handshaking complete _" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Acknowledgement timed out, resending sequence number and acknowledgement" << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
```

//there's more else if statements underneath, but it never goes there

No matter what, at this point it returns 0. I have seen the client and server send information to each other through the socket, so I don't think I'm sending to the wrong address on the client side. Here's the client side code for sending that packet that select() is waiting for:

```
buff[0] = _seqNum;
res = sendto(_socket, buff, 2, 0, (LPSOCKADDR) &sa_in, sizeof(SOCKADDR));
```

I can't be the only one whose ever had this problem, does anyone know how to address this?

Edit: Someone asked where _sockAddr is being filled out, so I'll include that here: Somewhere in there a ClienThread class is instantiated, and you can see a sockaddr_in being passed in.

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        // Wait for connection
        cout << "Waiting for incoming connection... ";

        sockaddr_in clientSockAddr;
        //  int clientSockSize = sizeof(clientSockAddr);

        // Listen in on the bound socket:
        //  hClientSocket = accept(hSocket,
        //  reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&clientSockAddr),
        //  &clientSockSize);
        unsigned char seqNum = 0; 

        int addrSize = sizeof(clientSockAddr);
        //wait for a connection
        int res=0;

        //loop until we get a packet that's from someone new
        bool blocking = true;

        while(blocking)
        {
            res = recvfrom(hSocket, buff, strlen(buff), 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&clientSockAddr, &addrSize);         
            bool foundMatch = false;
            //check if we're already handling this client. If so, keep blocking. Otherwise, break out of the loop
            for(list<ClientThread*>::iterator it = clientList.begin(); it != clientList.end(); it++)
            {
                //compare network addresses
                if((*it)->GetSockAddr().sin_addr.S_un.S_addr == clientSockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr)
                {
                    foundMatch = true; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!foundMatch)
            {
                blocking = false;
            }
        }
        err =  WSAGetLastError();  


        // Check if we can create a new client thread
        if(res != SOCKET_ERROR && res != 0)
        {
            seqNum = (unsigned char) buff[0]; //get the sequence number for handshaking
            cout << "accepted connection from: " << GetHostDescription(clientSockAddr) << endl;
            //start a client thread, to handle requests from this client.
            ClientThread* pThread = new ClientThread(hSocket, clientSockAddr, this, seqNum);
            clientList.push_back(pThread);
            pThread->start(); 
        }
    //  if (hClientSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    //      throw "accept function failed.";
    }
    catch(char* ex)
    {
        cerr << "\nError: " << ex << endl;
        bSuccess = false; 
    }

}
```

Edit2: Upon further debugging, I've found that the calls to sendto are reaching their intended target, since messages are received with calls to recvfrom, just not with select. However, I need to be able to use a non-blocking call.

Comment: Why did you choose `0` for the first argument to `select`?

Comment: What is the value of _rttInfo.timeout? (ie. How do we know that's not zero?) Also - is this a cut-down example? Because otherwise, if you only have 1 socket you're waiting on and no other logic to process, you don't need select.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Specifying 0 is fine - in Windows the 'nfds' parameter is ignored and is only provided for compatibility with Berkeley sockets.

Comment: @NikB: Okay, that's a good reason.

Comment: @Kylotan: _rttInfo.timeout starts out as about 450ms. I multiply by 1000 to get the microseconds.

Comment: While you're debugging this, set the timeout to a large number, eg. 10 seconds. 450ms is a very short window to expect another process to send a message in and too short for you to easily tell if the select call is honouring that time period. Beyond that, I recommend using Wireshark to see if the data actually comes to your system or not.

Answer (score 3):

`sendto()` is likely failing, but you are not checking it for any errors.  `sizeof(SOCKADDR)` is the wrong thing to use in the last parameter.  Use `sizeof(_sockAddr)` instead:

```
if (sendto(_clientSocket, buff, 2, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&_sockAddr, sizeof(_sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Handshaking failed, error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Make sure your `_sockAddr` variable is a valid `sockaddr_in`, `sockaddr_in6`, or `sockaddr_storage`, **NOT** a `sockaddr`.

On a separate note, assuming `_rttInfo.timeout` is expressed in milliseconds, your `timeout.tv_usec` value is being calculated wrong.  It should be like this instead:

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = _rttInfo.timeout / 1000;
timeout.tv_usec = (_rttInfo.timeout % 1000) * 1000;
```

Comment: I've tried changing the sendto like you said, but the server still has a problem. Also, I checked the sendto line, and no error value is generated.

Comment: Did you verify with a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, that the data is actually being tranmitted to the correct address?  What is your `_sockAddr` variable actually declared as and how are you filling it in? Did you verify that the receiver is actually receiving the data and sending an acknowledgement back?

Comment: I may try the packet sniffer idea, I'll let you know how that works out.

Comment: @user1058303: you did not include the actual declaration of the `_sockAddr` variable, so I have to assume it is a `sockaddr_in`. You showed code that is filling a `sa_in` variable, not the `_sockAddr` variable. BTW, `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Comment: You have introduced a new wrinkle into the equation. You are creating threads to manage known clients. If those threads are the ones calling `select()` then your use to `recvfrom()` in the main loop is interfering with your threads ability to receive per-client data. That would account for the timeouts. What you are attempting to do is not well-suited for UDP. You should get rid of your threads altogether. If you can't, at least remove the `select()` and `recvfrom()` calls from them and let your main loop do all of the reading, routing packets to threads as needed for further processing.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please include such important details, like threading information, otherwise you just waste people's time trying to guess what your system is doing.

Comment: The thought had occured to me that that was the problem, so I tried temporarily making it so the "main" thread wouldn't call recvfrom anymore, unfortunately, I still had the problem. However, your idea of using one thread might work. I'll have to give this some thought, as this should be able to handle multiple clients, and both sides should be able to handle lost packets. Its an FTP program, but it has to use UDP. Sorry for not including more information.

Comment: For UDP, definately only have 1 reading thread, even if there are multiple clients. Just keep track of each client and perform timeout logic periodically so you can remove clients that you have not seen traffic from for awhile if they do not explicitally log out of your server.

Comment: FYI, there is an existing UDP-based FTP protocol called [TFTP](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350), you should look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Predictably, select times out because you ask for a timeout (based on whatever value rttInfo contains). If you want to wait longer, adjust rttInfo, or if you want to wait until something happens then specify a null value for the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Select times out because you set a timeout. If you want blocking operations you need timeout to be null: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx

As you said, first parameter seems to be ignored. Something on the lines:

```
int res = select(0, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: The idea for this project is that this is a UDP program that will sometimes lose packets. They even provided us with a "router" program that will automatically lose a %age of the packets (I'm not using it right now). When sending packets from one host to the other, one will send a packet, wait for an acknowledgement, then send the next. If you don't receive an acknowledgement within a certain amount of time, you've got to resend the packet. Blocking would cause a host to wait forever when a packet is lost. I've tried doing this with 2 second timeouts, it still doesn't work.